# ERROR 010555: Internal error in Sample: %s. Failed to execute (ExtractMultiValuesToPoints)

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, point, spatial-analyst, error-010555

I'm trying to run the following code to extract different types of climate data for various points:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *


# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = r"X:\AugustComplex"

inRaster = "BurnSev_IA.img"
outPoint = "FirePts.shp"
field="VALUE"

# Execute RasterToPoint
arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(inRaster, outPoint, field)

# Bring in the boundary and buffer it by 500m
boundary = "Boundary.shp"
boundaryBuffer = "NewFire_Boundary_500mBuffer.shp"
distanceField = 500
sideType = "FULL"
endType = "ROUND"
dissolveType = "ALL"
dissolveField = ""
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(boundary, boundaryBuffer, distanceField, sideType, endType, dissolveType, dissolveField)

# Clip points to buffer
in_features = "FirePts.shp"
clip_features = "NewFire_Boundary_500mBuffer.shp"
out_feature_class = "FirePts_clp.shp"
xy_tolerance = ""

# Execute Clip
arcpy.Clip_analysis(in_features, clip_features, out_feature_class, xy_tolerance)

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

inPointFeatures = "FirePts_clp.shp"
# Climate variables
inRasterList2 = [["AET.tif", "AET"],
                 ["Snowpack.tif", "Snowpack"],
                 ["CWD.tif", "CWDeficit"],
                 ["PPT.tif", "PPT"]]

# Execute ExtractValuesToPoints
ExtractMultiValuesToPoints(inPointFeatures, inRasterList2)
```

When I try to run this, I get:

```
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
  File "e:\arcgis\desktop10.7\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py",
    line 7407, in ExtractMultiValuesToPoints     bilinear_interpolate_values)
  File "e:\arcgis\desktop10.7\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py",
    line 53, in swapper     result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "e:\arcgis\desktop10.7\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py",
    line 7402, in Wrapper     bilinear_interpolate_values)
  File "e:\arcgis\desktop10.7\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py",
    line 510, in <lambda>     return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
ExecuteError: ERROR 010555: Internal error in Sample: %s.
Failed to execute (ExtractMultiValuesToPoints).
```

It might be worth noting that the block before that uses the same function and works fine. I haven't been able to find much about what this error means.

Any suggestions for what to try?

Comment: Have you set `arcpy.env.workspace` to the folder where the rasters are located?

Comment: Yes! I recently tried running the rasters one at a time, and it worked for the AET and CWD rasters, but the PPT and Snowpack rasters gave me the same error.